# python - nested class access modifier

Tags: python, nested, private, python-3.5

I'm trying to make an instance of a `__Profile` class in the constructor of the `__Team` class, but I can't get access to `__Profile`. How should I do it?

This is my code

```
class SlackApi:
    # my work
    class __Team:
        class __Profile:
            def get(self):
                # my work 
        def __init__(self, slackApi):
            self.slackApi = slackApi
            self.profile = __Profile()
            self.profile = __Team.__Profile()
            self.profile = SlackApi.__Team.__Profile()
            # I tried to all of these case, but I failed
            # I need to keep '__Team', '__Profile' class as private class
```

My python version is 3.5.1

Comment: Why are you using nested classes and `__mangled_names` at all? *"I need to keep `__Team`, `__Profile` class as private class"* - why?

Comment: When you try to implement access modifiers (or any other feature) in a language which does not support them, you achieve two things: 1) you do not get satisfactory results, and 2) you do not benefit from the features which the language does support. It is kind of like skiing on a bycicle: worse than skiing and worse than cycling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not have access modifiers. If you try to treat `__` like a traditional `private` access modifier, this is one of the problems you get. Leading double underscores cause name mangling - a name `__bar` inside a `class Foo` (or `class __Foo`, or any number of leading underscores before `Foo`) will be mangled to `_Foo__bar`.

If you really want to keep those leading double underscores, you'll have to explicitly mangle the names yourself:

```
self.profile = SlackApi._SlackApi__Team._Team__Profile()
```

This is also how you would access the `__Profile` class from outside of `SlackApi` altogether, so you're basically bypassing any pretense that these things are private.

Answer (score 0):

You MAY access like so:

```
SlackApi._SlackApi__Team._Team__Profile
```

or like so:

```
self._Team__Profile
```

But that's just wrong. For your own convenience, don't make them a private class.